# Reading specific positions in a group to create new rows in a column R

Tags: r

I have multiple csv files with a double column structure. Once the file is in R it looks like this

```
# A tibble: 18 x 3
# Groups:   group [2]
   V1                        V2                                          group
   <chr>                     <chr>                                       <int>
 1 Sample File               "C:\\Data\\CPC\\COALA_CPC3776_20200129.xls"     0
 2 Model                     "3776"                                          0
 3 Sample #                  "1"                                             1
 4 Start Date                "01/29/20"                                      1
 5 Start Time                "03:06:08"                                      1
 6 Sample Length             "04:58"                                         1
 7 Averaging Interval (secs) "1.0"                                           1
 8 Title                     ""                                              1
 9 Instrument ID             "3776  70634317 2.7"                            1
10 Instrument Errors         "None"                                          1
11 Mean                      "4687.93"                                       1
12 Min                       "4215"                                          1
13 Max                       "5095"                                          1
14 Std. Dev.                 "208.445"                                       1
15 Time                      "Concentration (#/cm³)"                         1
16 03:06:09                  "4581"                                          1
17 03:06:10                  "4673"                                          1
18 03:06:11                  "4657"                                          1
```

This format repeats every 5 minutes. I want to move the date and sample # to new columns and then remove all that other lines that are between Sample File to Std.Dev. in V1 to get something like this.

```
   time concentration     date sample
1 02:02:02          1200 01/01/01      2
2 02:02:03          1300 01/01/01      2
3 02:03:03          4000 01/01/01      2
```

I can group the data by Sample # but then I dont know how to proceed.
This is my code so far

```
cpc_files <- list.files(pattern = '*.xls',path = 'input/CPC/')

cpc_raw <- do.call("rbind",  ##Apply the bind to the files
        lapply(cpc_files, ##call the list
               function(x)  ##apply the next function
                 read.table(paste("input/CPC/", x, sep=''),sep=',',fill = T, header = F, 
                          stringsAsFactors = FALSE,comment.char = "",
                          col.names = paste0("V",seq_len(max(count.fields("input/CPC/COALA_CPC3776_20200129.xls", sep = ','))))))) ##Read all the files filling the blanks with NAs

cpc_fix <- cpc_raw%>%select(V1,V2)%>%
          group_by(group = cumsum(V1 == "Sample #"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it dividing the process into two parts:

1. Moving date and sample to a new column:

   cpc_fix <- cpc_raw%>%select(V1,V2)%>%
         group_by(group = cumsum(V1 == "Sample #"))%>%
         mutate(date= V2[V1=='Start Date'][1],
                sample=V2[V1=='Sample #'][1])%>%
         ungroup()
2. Remove everything that is not a Time object like using Alexander suggestion:

   cpc_clean <- cpc_fix[grep(pattern="[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]", cpc_fix$V1, perl=TRUE), ]

   colnames(cpc_clean) <- c('time','concentration','group','date','sample')

Answer (score 0):

I simplified your input into 2 columns but this should be a good start.

```
x <- read.csv(file = '~/file.csv', stringsAsFactors = F)

df <- cbind(t(x$V2[1:(which('Time'==x$V1)-1)]), 
           x[(which('Time'==x$V1)+1):nrow(x),], stringsAsFactors = F)

colnames(df) <- unlist(c(x$V1[1:(which('Time'==x$V1)-1)], 
                                 x[(which('Time'==x$V1)),]))
```

The first argument to `cbind` is the metadata (row 1 to where it finds `'Time'`) and the second is the samples (everything after `'Time'`). The same logic for setting the column names. You can also store the names as a row if you want.

```
df2 <- rbind(colnames(df), df)
```

Comment: Will this logic work for different rows matching 'Time'? Because I run it and seems to struggle with this. What I guess is part of the solution but I had not figured out how is grouping my data per Sample number. That will create a manageable group? and maybe I can get the date and sample # from each group and then replace them in the df

Comment: I tried your code but a got the next errors: Error: Argument 1 must have names
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In 1:(which("Time" == cpc_fix$V1) - 1) :
  numerical expression has 778 elements: only the first used
2: In (which("Time" == cpc_fix$V1) + 1):nrow(cpc_fix) :
  numerical expression has 778 elements: only the first used

Comment: @Jhonathan This is an extremely specific case. The above code should be ran through each sample individually (think `list.files` then `for` loop), then you can just `cbind` all the runs. The code also assumes the same file structure as above. There are many ways to do this but the general idea is to process the metadata and the sample data separately. My guess is that you fed it a file which had multiple (778?) samples data.

Comment: Another slightly more complex way I did it was extracting the rows using `grepl` where the `pattern="[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]"`. I quickly gave that one up in favor of doing it this way.